# Should a GitHub repository contain both the virtual environment and the environment.yaml file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, virtualenv

Good Afternoon,

Recently, I've created a project folder that shall be containing a virtual repository for certain libraries. An environment.yaml file can be utilize to set up this virtual repository if any other individual utilizing Conda would like to create it on their own local machine.

For me, to upload the project's folder along with the virtual environment through GitHub, would I need to include in the repository both the virtual environment folder AND the environment.yaml file that creates it?

For example:
[image]

The image above is inside the projects directory folder. Within you can see a folder called "front_end", which is the virtual environment and a yaml file called "front_end_venv", which is used to create the "front_end" virtual environment folder.

Would I need to include both files (virtual environment AND the Yaml file the creates it) into the same GitHub repository? The virtual environment folder will be containing some programmable code as well such as a GUI interface.

Thank you

Comment: Don't ever commit the virtualenv itself. It's specific to your own machine and won't work for anyone else (unless they're running the exact same OS with the same Python version installed in the same place with the same CPU architecture, etc)

Comment: You should not include any venv in a repository. The venv is created in local by the user and he installs all the dependency using requirements.txt or environment.yaml.

I recommend you put any venv folder in the .gitignore.

Comment: Never put in the repository stuff that can be generated by compiling or installing libraries/modules. Why explode the repository with stuff you can download

Comment: @Eloi Thank you for the response!

Where exactly would I place the projects .py files (the programs themselves) that would require the virtual environment to run? As in, if I have a .py file that utilizes a library from the virtual environment folder, would I need to place it inside a separate folder?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the response!

I never knew that about virtual repositories. I always thought they were just directories that contain specific libraries and such that anyone can download onto their system by downloading the repository itself.

Comment: @rioV8 Is that the reason why the folder contains so many files within? Python exe, libraries, etc.?

It looked way to large for me to implement into my directories folder so I wasn't so sure on whether or not I should have included it into the GitHub repo.

With that being the case, where would I place any .py programs that need the virtual environment to run? As in, let's say I have .py programs and each one requires seperate virtual repositories. How would I insert them into seperate folders with seperate virtual repositories for themselves?

Comment: you now talk about `virtual repositories`, what do you mean? A Virtual Environment is the same as a global Python install with added installed modules, only you can switch the added modules by switching the Virt Env. Just activate the Virt Env. And import the modules as needed. The location of your .py files is not important with respect to the stuff in the Virt Env.

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you for the explanation!

I finally got what virtual environments are when you said "A Virtual Environment is the same as a global Python install with added installed modules, only you can switch the added modules by switching the Virt Env." In other words, activate the venv if I want a specfic python and libraries to run for a specific project. Regardless where my .py files are, the venv activates all around the PC, so it doesn't matter as much. Now I get it! Thank you!

Comment: Hi omar7439, Welcome to StackOverflow. glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @JialeDu How do I accept one of the answers above?

I don't see any green check marks for me to accept a reply as an acceptable answer to my question. All of these are just comments.

The only option I'm provided is a flag.

Comment: *Please consider **answering** it and **accepting** it as an answer.*

Comment: You can't accept an answer since there are no answers here, it's all just comments :)

Comment: That said, saying the venv "activates all around the PC" -- it's hard for me to say if that's accurate. It activates for _the current shell session and any subprocesses of that session_, but its scope isn't limited to a particular directory.